# Perform animation only once inside getView() , even if getView() is called multiple times

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have come across many such questions similar to mine.
But i have a slightly different question and i could not find any answer yet.

I have written a CustomAdapter for my ListView.
I wanted to try something new by implementing animations for my ListView items.
Hence i have implemented bottom-to-up animation similar to Google+ card animations.
Here is the code of the animation.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), (position > lastPosition) ?    R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
animation.setDuration(400);
rowView.startAnimation(animation);
lastPosition = position;
```

I have written this code in the getView() of my CustomAdapter.

In my application i need to call the getView() method twice.
Everything works fine till here.

Now the problem i face because of calling getView() more than once is, the card animation too occurs twice one after the other as my list is loaded twice.

How can i make my animation to perform only once? even while it is in the getView() method?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can send any flag in your adapter and on the basis of flag value you can perform the animation stuff

Comment: @Anjali, i tried doing that but i still get the same result.
One list is loaded from a network call , at the same time other list is loaded from the data i pass through intent.So getView() is called twice.

Comment: @ShrutiDasgopal: how you are calling `getView()` again ?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, i am not calling getView() again. Its just that i store the list,(one from network call and other from intent) in say 'mListOfItems'. 

`customListAdapter = new GSSListAdapter(ListViewGalaxkeySecure.this, mListOfItems); mListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);`

Comment: you are setting data to list 2 times, so any way the list animation will happen multiple times. Better pass a boolean variable to adapter constructor after getting data from intent with value true and next as false. so first will animate the list and the next wont since the passed boolean variable is false.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more flag in  `GSSListAdapter` class constructor to check is `getView` method is called first time or second time:

```
public boolean isShowAnimation=false;

 GSSListAdapter(...,...,boolean isShowAnimation){
  ...
  this.isShowAnimation=isShowAnimation;
 }
```

now use `isShowAnimation` for checking perform Animation or not in `getView` method of Adapter.